# IBatis and decode parameter mapping in resultMap

Tags: ibatis

I am new to Ibatis. I have a query in Oracle which returns `true` or `false` using decode function:

`SELECT decode(phone_number,null,null,'true') as GROUP_ASSIGNED`  ----- rest of the query

In this case how to map the `resultset` to the IBatis `resultmap`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the Oracle decode() function is just a if-then-else statement in disguise, you'd map the result (GROUP_ASSIGNED) column to an object property just like you would map any other returned column.  Assuming you are mapping to an object with a property named GroupAssigned:

```
<resultMap ....
  <result property="GroupAssigned" column="GROUP_ASSIGNED" />
```